# For every $\lambda\neq0$ in $P(a)$, $\delta-\lambda I$ annihilates nonzero element in $D$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have problem to understand the term "annihilate". What does it mean that for every $\lambda\neq0$ in $P(a)$, $\delta-\lambda I$ annihilates nonzero element in $D$?

$D$ is a division ring,

$P(a)$ is a field obtained by adjoining $a$ to a prime field $P$,

$ \lambda\in P(a)$

$\delta$ is a mapping from $D$ to $D$ defined by $\delta(x)=xa-ax$,

$\lambda I$ is a identical mapping defined by $ \lambda I:\, x\rightarrow\lambda x$. This mapping commutes with $\delta$ for every $ \lambda\in P(a)$.

Thank you.

Comment: "annihilates" means "maps to zero", i.e. $(\delta - \lambda I)x = 0$ for some $x \ne 0$.

Comment: @njguliyev Hi! Could you consider making your comment an answer? We would rather resolve this question than let it sit around. Thanks!

Comment: @rschwieb, done.

Comment: Dear Monika, just out of curiosity, are you working through the proof of Wedderburn's Little Theorem (the particular proof due to Herstein)? Based on your last 3 questions, I naturally came to this conclusion :) I myself read this beautiful proof back in March.

Answer (score 3):

Here "annihilates" means "maps to zero", i.e. $(\delta−\lambda I)x=0$ for some $x \ne 0$.