# Wedderburn's theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-fields

I am trying to understand the proof of Wedderburn theorem and I have a problem to understand the part of it. I don't know how to get the equation nr 1: $a_{1}b_{1}=\mu b_{1}a_{1}$ Could anyone elaborate on this, please?

[image]

Thank you.

[Source](http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~marin/une_autre_crypto/articles_et_extraits_livres/Herstein-Wedderburn.pdf).

Comment: I guess I [was right](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482171/for-every-lambda-neq0-in-pa-delta-lambda-i-annihilates-nonzero-eleme#comment1038726_482171) :)

Answer (score 1):

**Define** $\mu = a_1b_1a_1^{-1}b_1^{-1}$ so that $(1)$ holds.  Then all you need is $\mu \in Z$.  Notice $bab^{-1} = \lambda a$, where $\lambda \in Z$, has already been established so
$$\mu = a_1b_1a_1^{-1}b_1^{-1} = a^mb^na^{-m}b^{-n} = a^m\lambda^{-m}a^{-m} = \lambda^{-m}$$